# Online Marketing company want me to share my Google Account login details?

Tags: access-control, google, third-party

We are a small business and use "[Google Apps for Work](https://www.google.com/intx/en_uk/work/apps/business/)" and my google apps account was used to set up the business's "[Google My Business](https://www.google.ie/business/)" and related Google+ pages

We have now engaged an online marketing company to manage the business's online local marketing. But they are asking us to share our Google Account login details so they can manage the business's "Google My Business" and related Google+ pages.

I have no issue letting them into any online marketing related tools such as the Google My Business account and related Google+ pages (and I presume they may also want access to our Google Analytics), but the same Google account login details would also give them access to my other Google business apps such as my gmail and google drive which I am very uncomfortable with.

How can I give them access to the google marketing tools, which were set up under my name, but not the more sensitive apps? What is the proper security practice to allow third parties to access the marketing tools?

Comment: This might be a better question for Google Apps Support.

Comment: See also my answer at [Is it OK to tell your password to your company's sysadmin?](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/5542/33). Different context, same answer - passwords are NEVER to be shared.

Comment: Can you not create a new account (in your google apps domain) for the marketing company, and give that account access to the MyBusiness and other company Google+ pages? (I am not familiar with those services...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Google My Business (and related services) [you can add/remove managers](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3403100?hl=en) to the business account without having to share credentials. The marketing company would need to have or create a Google account that you can then add to your My Business account in the Managers tab of your settings. Note that only the Owner on the account can add new managers.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed that is a security issue and if they have your login details, any angelic person working for that company who manages clients like you may not resist to the temptation in going further by simple curiosity or for more other serious reason to check your Gmail or other accounts.

The only solution that remains to you is to contact that company to make a deal about your privacy issues, but still this is not enough and trust in this case is your first threat, but if you do this step and use it in conjunction with the [Last account activity](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938?hl=en) you will know at least if any person other than you has used your Gmail account (in which case you may run a further investigation)